# Get model attribute's type in Yii2

Tags: php, yii, metadata, yii2

How can I check type (column type) of model's attribute  in Yii2?

[This old Yii Forum answer](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/34249-attribute-retrieved-as-string-instead-of-int/page__view__findpost__p__185266) gave me a conclusion, that in Yii1 I can use something like that:

```
$model->getMetaData()->columns['attribute-name']->type;
```

But I was unsuccessful in porting this solution to Yii2. Can someone help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use:

```
$model->getTableSchema()->getColumn('attr')
```

or:

```
$model->getTableSchema()->columns['attr']
```

and then read `dbType`, `phpType` or `type`, according to what... type of type you're looking for.

For example:

```
$model->getTableSchema()->columns['attr']->type
```

Comment: Thanks! I've edited your answer and added some (hopefully useful) stuff.